# visual change event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there not an event that occurs only when there has been some sort of visual change to an object. So for example if it were a video or animated object it would be firing as often as EnterFrame.  However, if it were some sort of input control just sitting there doing nothing visually, then the event wouldn't fire until the visual state changed as a result of some sort of user input for example.

I've tried dozen's of events and none of them seem to fire this way.

Answer (score 0):

For visual components about the closest you're going to get is FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE which will fire after an object has it's commitProperties(), measure() and updateDisplayList() called. If you're subclassing the component, then overriding updateDisplayList() and handling (or throwing you're own event) in there would ensure that you're only getting the event when something visual changes.

For video, you'll want to listen to VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE